# Removing ashes of 3d printing resin

Tags: acid-base, polymers, carbon-family

I'm not a chemist so excuse me if my question will bite your eye or ear.

A resin 3d printing uses polymers that cure under exposure to UV light. There is a special sort of 3d printing resins made for casting metals. Basically these resins produce smaller amount of ash during casting. I'm looking for a way to clean-out a metallic part made from aluminium (or other metals in a list below) from 3d printing-resin-ash that occurs in place of contact with metal.

I'm unable to apply mechanical force to clean out the model due to it's geometry so naturally I would like dissolve the remnants of polymer (supposedly carbon) with some sort of acid or anything else that would eat-out ash while preserving metal as much as feasible.

The list of metals can be any of the following:

Aluminum, chrome, copper, nickel, steel, silver (ordered from most preferable to least preferable)

Is there a chemical compound capable of achieving the goal.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the polymer ash is substantially carbon, **nothing** can dissolve carbon that would not destroy the mold.

Comment: One of my friends suggested burning it in pure oxygen, which should gradually oxidise C into CO and CO2? Is it true?

Comment: Can your mold withstand the temperature of burning carbon??? Use an oxyacetylene torch, then.